# Stop D3 parsing date strings

Tags: javascript, d3.js, time

This appears to be D3's default behavior, since no specific configuration has been made.

If it gets a `2019-10-26` string (which it recognizes as time), D3 will format it as `Sat Oct 26 2019 02:00:00 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time)`.

I can check what type of data is being read and have a `d3-format` spec for different number formats, which looks like this (generating a table):

```
).selectAll("td").text(d =>
    (__ => __ && ["INTEGER", "FLOAT"].includes(__.dataType) ? formatNumber(__.format)(d.value) : d.value)
    (window.dimensions.find(({ name }) => name === d.column))
);
```

I will do the same for time types, but I only want time formatting when I call it. I don't want D3 recognizing time types on its own. Ideally, in the above code, when it returns just `d.value`, it would return `2019-10-26` - unformatted.

Is there any way to disable the default time formatting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found where the type coercion was taking place: we were calling `csvParse` from `d3-dsv`, and were providing it with the default, optional `autoType`.

The call was:

```
csvParse(__.filter(row => row[0] !== "#").join("\n"), autoType)
```

and is now:

```
csvParse(__.filter(row => row[0] !== "#").join("\n"), myAutoType)
```